# Dynamic Button Click on Tab Control - Tab Pages C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2019, tabcontrol, vb.net-2010

I have an application that needs to click on button located on tab pages. So for example:

Tabcontrol has Tabpage1, Tabpage2, .... TabpageN

and each tabpage has a buttonX that performs a taskX.

Now supposing, I'm on TabPage1 and I want to Click ButtonX on Tabpage3 without changing tabindex/selectedindex. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally one would use [PerformClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) but I've noticed it failing on TabControl. So if not dependent on EventArgs, create a sub method for the click event e.g.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1PerformClick();
}

private void Button1PerformClick()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button1");
}
```

Than calling

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1PerformClick();
}
```

Doesn't matter in regards to which tab the button is on in this case.